# webapi IPrincipal and authorize

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

this is about security MVC4 RC and "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi".

I create a custom Identity : System.Security.Principal.IIdentity where i store some valuable string's and int's in the authentication cookie:

```
  [Serializable]
public class SiteIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public SiteIdentity(string name, string displayName, int userId, int siteId)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
        this.UserId = userId;
        this.SiteId = siteId;

    }

    public SiteIdentity(string name, UserInfo userInfo)
        : this(name, userInfo.DisplayName, userInfo.UserId, userInfo.SiteId)
    {
        if (userInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userInfo");
        this.AuthenticationType = userInfo.AutheticationType;
        this.ClaimsIdentifier = userInfo.ClaimsIdentifier;
    }

    public SiteIdentity(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
        : this(ticket.Name, UserInfo.FromString(ticket.UserData))
    {
        if (ticket == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ticket");
    }
```

... not complete but i think you guess.

But first of all the structure of my webapi controller. I have created and extension controller, from where i extend all my webapi controllers:

```
   public class _AuthorizedApiController : ApiController
{

        protected readonly Site.Web.Domain.Services.IUserServices _userServices;

        public _AuthorizedApiController(Site.Web.Domain.Services.IUserServices userServices)
        {
            if (userServices == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userServices");
            this._userServices = userServices;

        }

        protected int CurrentUserId
        {
            get { return this.User.SiteIdentity().UserId; }
        }

        private Site.Web.Domain.Models.User currentUser;

        public Site.Web.Domain.Models.User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currentUser ??
                       (this.currentUser = this._userServices.GetUserFromIdentity(this.User.SiteIdentity()));
            }
        }

        protected int CurrentSiteId
        {
            get { return this.User.SiteIdentity().SiteId; }
        }

}
```

so my webapi controller is:

```
    public class ServicioController : _AuthorizedApiController
{
    //http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api
    //http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

    static readonly IServicioStatusRepository repositoryServicioStatus = 
        new ServicioStatusRepository(new Site.Web.Data.DatabaseFactory());



    public ServicioController(Site.Web.Domain.Services.IUserServices userServices)
    : base(userServices)
    {

    }



    public IEnumerable<ServicioStatusA> GetServiciosStatus()
    {
        IEnumerable<ServicioStatusA> coleccion;
        var estevalor = CurrentUser.SiteId;
     }
```

As you can see i use IoC but the issue is that when i try to read CurrentUser.SiteId. I get this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity' to type 'Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity'.

in this return function:

```
       public static Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity SiteIdentity(this System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return (Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity)principal.Identity;
    }
```

I use this "artifact" in global.asax.cs to keep session and information:

```
    public override void Init()
    {
        this.PostAuthenticateRequest += this.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler;
        //            this.EndRequest += this.EndRequestHandler;

        base.Init();
    }


    private void PostAuthenticateRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            string esto = "popopopopo";
        }


        HttpCookie authCookie = this.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (IsValidAuthCookie(authCookie))
        {
            // var formsAuthentication = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IFormsAuthentication>();
            var formsAuthentication = new FormsAuthenticationService();

            var ticket = formsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var siteIdentity = new SiteIdentity(ticket);
            this.Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(siteIdentity, null);

            // Reset cookie for a sliding expiration.
            formsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.Context, ticket);
        }
    }
```

and what i guess is that when there is a "normal" MVC call every works fine but when there is a webapi call i can recover everything from the cookie but i´ve got:

System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal
 + Identity: Site.Web.Model.SiteIdentity

instead of :

System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal
 + Identity: System.web.security.FormsIdentity

Thank you in advance for your support

ADEN-UM:

googling i try to keep the Identity in the thread also, so inside PostAuthenticateRequestHandler i type:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = this.Context.User;
```

but now i have for all request the following error in any request not only webapi:

```
     [SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity,Site.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection.get_RemoteIP() +0
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.GetRemoteAddress() +65
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_IsLocal() +23
   System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection.CustomErrorsEnabled(HttpRequest request) +86
   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.get_IsCustomErrorEnabled() +45
   System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) +72
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```